# Creating heap algorithm to output a list of all permutations, in base python without other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, heapsort

I am trying to build an algorithm which will output a list of all permutations of an inputted string and I am getting very lost, especially when it comes to heap algorithm. I tried to copy the code listed on the Wikipedia page to no avail. I want a solution in base Python.

```
# Desired output
heaps_func('art')  
['rta', 'tra', 'tar', 'rat', 'art', 'atr']

# Current code
def heaps_func(a):
    lst=[a]
    l=len(a)
    if len(a)==1:
        return lst
    else:
        for x in range(len(a)-1):
            if x<(l-1):
                if l%2==0:
                    k=list(a)
                    p=k[i]
                    k[i]=k[l-1]
                    k[l-1]=p
                    k=''.join(k)
                    lst.append(k)
                else:
                    k=list(a)
                    p=k[0]
                    k[0]=k[l-1]
                    k[l-1]=p
                    k=''.join(k)
                    lst.append(k)

    return lst
```

Comment: It would help if you add a description for what you intend this code to do. Not just the outcome, but try to describe how you think your algorithm should work.

Comment: I think we should use the tag [heaps] rather than [heaps-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heaps-algorithm) which was only created 2/2019 and seems unnecessary, also is grammatically wrong. There is an existing discussion on Meta: [Resolve ambiguity of the \[heap\] tag between the data structure and the memory zone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297387/resolve-ambiguity-of-the-heap-tag-between-the-data-structure-and-the-memory-zo)

Comment: You write `heaps_func(art)` but that must have quotes around the string: `heaps_func('art')`

Comment: Thanks sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using recursion. Here I am goiing to add the python code for you.

```
def heaps_func(a,size):

    if size ==1:
        a = ''.join(a)
        print(a)
        return
    for i in range(size):
        heaps_func(a,size-1)
        if size%2==1:
            a[0],a[size-1]=a[size-1],a[0]
        else:
            a[i], a[size - 1] = a[size - 1], a[i]


heaps_func(list('art'),3)
```

If the given string contains duplicate characters, this program will also print duplicate element. For example, in string "arr", 'r' contains two times. And output of this program will be :

> arr rar rar arr rra rra

To get rid of this, we can use a list and before printing we will search on that list whether this element exist in the list or not. If not exist then we will print it and store it on the list.

Programs:

```
def heaps_func(a,size,listofwords):
    if size ==1:
        a = ''.join(a)
        #print(a)
        if listofwords.count(a)==0:
            print(a)
            listofwords.append(a)
        return
    for i in range(size):
        heaps_func(a,size-1,listofwords)
        if size%2==1:
            a[0],a[size-1]=a[size-1],a[0]
        else:
            a[i], a[size - 1] = a[size - 1], a[i]

listofwords=[]
heaps_func(list('arr'),len('arr'),listofwords)
```

for details please read the following link . But there it is described in C/C++.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heaps-algorithm-for-generating-permutations/

Comment: Thanks! any chance could you explain what the n parameter does? it seems like it does not do any thing.

Comment: Also it seems that this produces alot of duplicates within the list also.

Comment: I's it printing duplicates?

Comment: Also, if the string contains duplicate character it Will print duplicate.so we can use map for keeping track whether this string printed before or not.